# Convert base y to base 10

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, number-systems

I have a problem to find base y.  The equation given is

($1111011$)<sub>gray</sub> + ($123$)<sub>y</sub> + ($211.1$)<sub>3</sub> + ($34.4$)<sub>$6$</sub> = (CD)<sub>$16$</sub> + ($40$)<sub>y</sub> - ($10010$)<sub>BCD</sub>.

I am able to simplify by converting everything to base $10$ but cannot figure out how to find base y.

The simplified, converted equation becomes ($123$)<sub>y</sub> - ($40$)<sub>y</sub> = ($66$)<sub>$10$</sub>.

Any help would be grateful, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your simplified, converted equation is correct, i.e. that $(123)_y-(40)_y=(66)_{10}$, we can write this as: $$1\cdot y^2+2\cdot y+3-(4\cdot y+0)=6\cdot 10+6$$ which we can simplify to: $$y^2-2y-63=0$$ Solving for $y$ then yields $y=1\pm 8$. Clearly $y\neq -7$, so we get $y=9$.